# CompareTo and collections.sort() errors

Tags: java, sorting

I'm having trouble with the collections.sort because it's not sorting anything. I have two classes which one class has a compareTo method that compares dates and the other class has a Collections.sort which sort the dates. My code compiles and run with no errors but the ArrayList is not sorted, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and why the Collections.sort is not working.

Here is the code:

```
public class CalendarDate implements Comparable<CalendarDate>{ 

    private int month;
    private int day;

    //Constructor
    public CalendarDate(int month, int day){
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    //CompareTo method
    public int CompareTo(CalendarDate other){
        if(month != other.month){
             return month - other.month;
        } 
        else {
            return day - other.day;
        }
    }


    //Getters
    public int getMonth(){
        return month;
    }

    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }

    //toString method
    public String toString(){
        return month + "/" + day;
    }

public int compareTo(CalendarDate other) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;


public class CalendarDateSort {
public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<CalendarDate> list = new ArrayList<CalendarDate>();

    list.add(new CalendarDate(1, 11)); 
    list.add(new CalendarDate(5, 15 )); 
    list.add(new CalendarDate(3, 8)); 
    list.add(new CalendarDate(7, 10)); 
    list.add(new CalendarDate(3, 16)); 


    System.out.println("dates before sorting = " + list);
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println("dates after sorting = " + list);        
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CompareTo` method that does a comparison has a typo and is named differently. Java identifiers are case-sensitive. The `compareTo` that actually gets called always returns 0 (indicating all elements are equal).

```
public class CalendarDate implements Comparable<CalendarDate>{

    // doesn't get called by sort
    public int CompareTo(CalendarDate other){
        if(month != other.month){
             return month - other.month;
        } 
        else {
            return day - other.day;
        }
    }

    // gets called by sort
    public int compareTo(CalendarDate other) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Use the `@Override` annotation. It will generate a compilation error if you make this kind of mistake.

See also [Overriding and Hiding Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

> When overriding a method, you might want to use the @Override annotation that instructs the compiler that you intend to override a method in the superclass. If, for some reason, the compiler detects that the method does not exist in one of the superclasses, then it will generate an error.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a fixed value of `0` which causes the list entries never to be sorted. The  logic inside the `CompareTo` method needs to be contained within the `compareTo` method

```
@Override
public int compareTo(CalendarDate other) {
    if (month != other.month) {
        return month - other.month;
    } else {
        return day - other.day;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `compareTo(CalendarDate)` method always returns 0.

Replace `return 0` with the code from the bogus `CompareTo()` method. Add an `@Override` annotation to `compareTo()` (and other methods that you expect to match some interface); this will cause a compiler error if you typo the method name or mess up the signature.

Comment: it works now thank you, but I have a question now. I don't understand Why does it has to be overriding

Comment: @Ruben When you implement `compareTo`, it is called an override (whether you annotate it or not).